# WINAPI: Window client area not lining up with the window

Tags: c, winapi

The client area of my window is not aligning properly with the outer non-client area. Take a look, this is when I am not touching the window, just after I launch it:

[image]

It's not aligned, although all dimensions across all functions are ok, 500x500 to be exact.

Now, when I resize it, it kind of aligns correctly:

[image]

```
HWND Window = CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            WindowClass.lpszClassName,
            "Handmade Hero",
            WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            500,
            500,
            0,
            0,
            Instance,
            0);


        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(Window, &rect);
        Win32AllocateMemoryBuffer(&GlobalBackBuffer, rect.right, rect.bottom);
```

Message handling:

```
case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT Paint;
            HDC DeviceContext = BeginPaint(Window, &Paint);
            Dimension rect;
            GetClientRect(Window, &rect);

            Win32DisplayBufferInWindow(DeviceContext, &GlobalBackBuffer, Dimension.right, Dimension.bottom);
            EndPaint(Window, &Paint);
        } break;
```

The stretchdbits:

```
    StretchDIBits(DeviceContext,
        0, 0, WindowWidth, WindowHeight,
        0, 0, Buffer->BitmapWidth, Buffer->BitmapHeight,
        Buffer->BitmapMemory,
        &Buffer->BitmapInfo,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

I've been tracking the dimensions across all the program in VS debugger, but couldn't track the problem. Maybe your intuition would spot something?

Comment: Questions on SO are suppoused to be **specific** enough for us to answer them. Answering must never require intuition. Please post a [MCVE] and read [ask].

Comment: When creating a window, you are passing *window* coordinates, not client coordinates. 500x500 includes all the non-client areas. If you need to create a client area of a particular size, call [AdjustWindowRectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx). I'm not sure this is what you are asking for. Your question isn't clear enough to know.

Comment: If your functions are expecting width/height values instead of right/bottom coordinates, you should be using `right - left`, `bottom - top` instead. The left/top values may not always be 0 like you are expecting. As such, you might also consider passing the left/top values to `StretchDIBits()` instead of 0s

Comment: After adjusting the DestX and DestY of destination rectangle origin point in StretchDIBits(), I got the image perfectly aligned with the desired window. (Also, it asks for destX, destY in logical units, these are pixels right?) BTW I did everything all of you mentioned, didn't do the trick. Apparently, the bitmap was offset in StretchDIBits() thus making it misaligned. [HAVE A LOOK](https://i.imgur.com/uOPrTVv.png)